Unable to upgrade node js from 14 to 20 version
Currently my project setup is in Node JS 14 and NPM 6. I tried to upgrade the node JS to 20, but I observed that it is not installing NPM 10 as part of Node JS 20 installation.
I have tried to run the application by keeping Node JS 20 with both npm versions i.e 6 and 10. But I am facing the below errors:
With Node JS 20 & NPM 10
lerna ERR! npm ci exited 1 in '@thub/common'
lerna ERR! npm ci stderr:
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "^>=16.8.5" of package "react@^>=16.8.5": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes

With Node JS 20 & NPM 6
opensslErrorStack: [
'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error',
'error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported'
],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

Can anyone help with the clear picture of node JS upgrade and the compatible versions of Node JS & NPM and if there are any official documentations.

Install legacy peer dependencies that help npm install packages without enforcing peer dependency checks, which is potentially useful for managing compatibility issues or older packages with incomplete peer dependency declarations. you can check more What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?.
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

But If you want to update dependency with the current node version manually
then you can do so by:

Use npm outdated to identify outdated dependencies.
Update dependencies by npm update to versions compatible with Node.js 20.
Recompile any native addons or packages if necessary.


NPM come's with node.js package, if you are facing any difficulty please use NVM package manager.

Hi Nitish, here the problem is how can we check the compatibility and what is the process or dependencies we need to update per the node upgrade
